# Get the value of visible column of JasperReports Server input control?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report in *JasperReports Server 5.2.0*, in this report I have two input control

first one is:

```
COUNTRY (value column- COUNTRY_ID, visible column- COUNTRY_NAME)
```

and another one is

```
STATES (value column- STATE_ID and visible column - STATE_NAME).
```

These two parameters I am passing to the report, now at the end of the report I want to show the input parameter selection value so user can see what he has selected. But I am not able to get the visible values of parameters. I can print only value column value.

So my question is there any way to print the visible column values of input control in reports?

Comment: This issue is already open: [Pass back Visible Columns/ListValues from multi-select and single select to the jrxml file as parameters.](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/4347). You can give a voice on it

Comment: Try this solution: [Input controls](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/529170/input-controls). It is about using paira of both values as *value column* (for example, separated by delimiter) and extracting the one part or another

Comment: You will get ids of States and Country in JRML file.Write a subquery for it.Then you will get those details to print in Report

Answer (score 0):

Till now , `Visible Columns` are not passed,where `Value Columns` are passed to Jrml File in Jasper.

```
 To answer you question There is a way to print the visible column values.
It can be done using Sub-queries, by using 'Value Column' passed to the JRML file.
Then add the subquery to your main query and it`s done!!
```

In the above scenario You can display

1. State Name

> `SELECT States.STATE_NAME from States WHERE state_id = $P{STATE_ID}` - If it is **Single Select** input control
>
> `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(States.STATE_NAME) from States WHERE state_id = $X{IN,state_id,STATE_ID}` - If it is **Multi-Select** input control

2. Country Name

> `SELECT Country.COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY WHERE country_id= $P{COUNTRY_NAME}` - If it is **Single Select** input control
>
> `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Country.COUNTRY_NAME) from COUNTRY WHERE country_id = $X{IN,state_id,STATE_ID}` - If it is **Multi-Select** input control

---

> Suppose this your main query where Country and State are missing..
>
> ```
> SELECT
>     `id`,
>     `product-id`,
>     `name`,
>     `description`,
>     `branch`,
>     `stock`,
>     `price`
> FROM
>     `products`
> WHERE
>     `name` LIKE "%car%"
> ```
>
> The modified query will looks like..
>
> ```
>     SELECT
>         `id`,
>         `product-id`,
>         `name`,
>         `description`,
>         `branch`,
>         `stock`,
>         `price`,
>         (SELECT States.STATE_NAME from States WHERE state_id = $P{STATE_ID}) as state,
> (SELECT Country.COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY WHERE country_id=P{COUNTRY_NAME}) as country
>     FROM
>         `products`
>     WHERE
>         `name` LIKE "%car%"
> ```